# How do you Unmarshall into the correct order in Go?

Tags: json, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

It seems that if I have an interface{} in Go in a particular order and I Marshal it into a []byte and then Unmarshal it back into an interface{}, it should retain the original order. It does not. The result is that DeepEqual fails to match the two as you can see in the program below.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var jd interface{}

    j := map[string]interface{}{
        "A": map[string]interface{}{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
        "B": map[string]interface{}{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
        "C": map[string]interface{}{
            "a": map[string]interface{}{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
            "b": map[string]interface{}{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
            "c": map[string]interface{}{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
        },
    }

    s, _ := json.Marshal(j)
    _ = json.Unmarshal(s, &jd)

    fmt.Println(string(s))
    fmt.Println(j)
    fmt.Println(jd)
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(j, jd) {
        fmt.Println("Fail!")
    }
}
```

The results from this program are random, but this is a typical result:

```
{"A":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},"B":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},"C":{"a":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},"b":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},"c":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}}}

map[B:map[a:1 b:2 c:3] C:map[c:map[a:1 b:2 c:3] a:map[b:2 c:3 a:1] b:map[a:1 b:2 c:3]] A:map[c:3 a:1 b:2]]

map[A:map[a:1 b:2 c:3] B:map[a:1 b:2 c:3] C:map[b:map[c:3 a:1 b:2] c:map[a:1 b:2 c:3] a:map[a:1 b:2 c:3]]]

Fail!
```

As you can see, the values Marshal into the original order, but Unmarshal into a random order (multiple runs of this program will produce different results). The result is that the DeepEqual comparison fails every time (so far).

Is this a bug in Go? Does anyone have a workaround that they can suggest?

Answer (score 5):

> [The Go Programming Language
>   Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [For statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)
>
> The iteration order over maps is not specified and is not guaranteed
>   to be the same from one iteration to the next.

By design, the iteration order over maps is pseudorandom.

Comment: Have to disagree strongly with this answer.  Iterator order does not explain the difference: `reflect.DeepEqual` is perfectly capable of comparing maps.  The implementation starting in http://golang.org/src/reflect/deepequal.go#L101 to around line 116 shows that the map comparison isn't affected by iteration order.  lossleader's answer is correct.

Comment: That is, this is encouraging the mistaken assumption that the original questioner had over the behavior of `reflect.DeepEqual`.  The questioner is attributing the inequality to the observation that the two values are printing differently.  In actuality, it is the difference in numeric *type* that's significant.  `reflect.DeepEqual` doesn't care how a value gets printed.

Answer (score 3):

The order of the map isn't why it is not equal. (If you unmarshall twice you will get two deeply equal maps that still differ randomly in order.)

[Unmarshalling a json number is float64](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal):

```
float64, for JSON numbers
```

It will work if you change your code as follows:

```
var num float64 = 0;
j := map[string]interface{}{
    "A": map[string]interface{}{"a": num+1, "b": num+2, "c": num+3},
    "B": map[string]interface{}{"a": num+1, "b": num+2, "c": num+3},
    "C": map[string]interface{}{
        "a": map[string]interface{}{"a": num+1, "b": num+2, "c": num+3},
        "b": map[string]interface{}{"a": num+1, "b": num+2, "c": num+3},
        "c": map[string]interface{}{"a": num+1, "b": num+2, "c": num+3},
    },
}
```

You can then change the type of num to anything else and it will fail.

Comment: I've tested with the change you suggested and it does indeed pass the DeepEqual despite the fact that the displayed map order is different. Thanks for your help.

An interesting note is that although the display is out of order, if you Marshal back to a string, the order is always restored. In other words, internally the data must be in the original order. Only the println display is out of order.

Comment: I had to look to be sure, but really go is sorting to canonicalize json format when marshalling: http://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L612 so quite a few go structs (in terms of types) map to a particular json representation which can then be unmarshalled to a specific go struct (in terms of types) that still has randomly ordered maps during runtime iteration.. A fun interface between strong typing + loose ordering and strong ordering + loose typing.